# Data.Vector.modify creates vector copies on each iteration

Tags: haskell, optimization, vector

Consider the example:

```
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as Vector
import Data.Vector.Unboxed (Vector)
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable as MVector

process :: [Int] -> Vector Int -> Vector Int
process [] v = v
process (x:xs) v = process xs $ Vector.modify modify v
  where
  modify mv = do
    old <- MVector.read mv x
    MVector.write mv x (old + 1)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print $ process [1, 1, 3, 1] $ Vector.replicate 10 0
```

In `core` on each iteration I see sequence of `newByteArray#`, `copyByteArray#`, `readIntArray#`, `writeIntArray#` and `unsafeFreezeByteArray#`. It definitely creates intermediate copies.

Documentation states:

> Apply a destructive operation to a vector. The operation will be
>   performed in place if it is safe to do so and will modify a copy of
>   the vector otherwise.

It is implemented as

```
modify p = new . New.modify p . clone
```

And there is `RULE`

```
"clone/new [Vector]" forall p.
  clone (new p) = p
```

From my (pretty limited) understanding, two successive `modify` should not create intermediate copies:

```
modify p2 . modify p1
=> new . New.modify p2 . clone . new . New.modify p1 . clone
=> new . New.modify p2 . New.modify p1 . clone
```

Why doesn't it work in the `process` function? I think it should:

```
process [1, 2] v
=> process [2] $ Vector.modify modify v
=> process [] $ Vector.modify modify $ Vector.modify modify v
=> Vector.modify modify $ Vector.modify modify v
=> the same as above
```

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's the recursion that's stopping it.

There's nowhere in the source code that says `modify` immediately followed by `modify`. Each iteration of the function calls `modify` again, but that happens at run-time, not compile-time. I think that's the problem. If you were to manually write three `modify` calls in a line, they would fuse.

I can't think of a way to make this fuse automatically. You could of course manually call `clone` and `new` yourself, but I can't think of a way to get the compiler to do this for you.

Comment: ah, recursion prevents inlining, so RULE doesn't fire. Correct?

Comment: Yes, RULE is a syntactic thing. If it finds an expression matching the one in the RULE, it fires. It looks after inlining so it can find more things, but it still needs to find it syntactically.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just produce a single call to `modify`?

```
import Control.Monad (forM_)

[...]

process :: [Int] -> Vector Int -> Vector Int
process xs v = Vector.modify modify v
  where
  modify mv = forM_ xs $ \ x -> do
    old <- MVector.read mv x
    MVector.write mv x (old + 1)
```

Comment: Because I already have pure function to fold my data (it is not a list actually). I can implement monadic version, but before doing that I want to know why I can't reuse existing one.

Comment: @Yuras I'm afraid I don't understand your comment.

Comment: Well, the `process` function is basically a `foldl (Vector.modify ...) <intial_vector> <list>`. I'm using custom data type, not a list, but the idea is the same. And for my data type I have function similar to `foldl`, but don't yet have analog for `foldM`. And it is not an instance of `Traversable`, so I can't use `forM`